# How to generate an array of words (e.g. value_1, value_2,..., value_#) where the number of words is equal to #?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dynamic

I have a variable (for example):

```
var numINeed = 4
```

I need to dynamically create an array like so:

```
var arrayINeed = ["value_1","value_2","value_3","value_4"]
```

Where the last item is formatted such that the # in value_# is equal to var numINeed, meaning that the length of arrayINeed = length of var numINeed

Attempted so far:

I've attempted to create the array using a for loop (I'm using Vue JS by the way)

```
      data: () => ({
          arrayINeed: [],
          variableA: []
      }),

      for (var i = 0; i<this.numINeed; ++i) {
        this.variableA = "value_" + i;
        this.arrayINeed.push(this.variableA);
      }
```

I believe this might be written wrongly. How might I be able to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited your code. Variable i is starting from zero, So I added one to it.

```js
var numINeed = 4;
arrayINeed = [];
for (var i = 0; i<numINeed; ++i) {
  let variableA = "value_" + (i+1);
  arrayINeed.push(variableA);
}
console.log(arrayINeed);
```

Answer (score 1):

using ES6:

```js
let arrayINeed = Array.from(Array(4), (_,x) => "value_" + (x+1));
console.log(arrayINeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

A short code could be this:

```js
var numINeed = 4;
    
var newArray = Array(numINeed).fill('').map((v, i) => `value_${i+1}`);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate array using `while` loop

```js
var numINeed = 4;
var arrayINeed = [];

var i = 1;
while (i < numINeed + 1) {
    arrayINeed.push("value_" + i);
    i++;
}

console.log(arrayINeed);
```